# Best Practice : Sharepoint 2010 WebPart development debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis, sharepoint-2010

We are 2 developers using remotely a server machine that hosts sharepoint 2010. Our problem is when we debug a webpart solution IIS restarts automatically so every time we have to wait for each other to finish debugging before we can test our own webpart.

any solution please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice for nearly any web development work is to setup every developer to have their own sandbox copy of the site. With SharePoint, this typically means a local virtual machine due to the nature of the beast.